# Metarig ring finger bends the wrong way

Tags: rigging

so ive been following the process of using the Metarig and all of the finders work fine exept for the ring fingers on each side. no matter if i use scaling or rotating the finger bends the wrong way
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Difficult to tell without seeing the blend file, but it looks as if the bone roll is wrong for all the bones on that finger. Select the armature, then the armature data properties (running man icon). Open the Viewport Display section on the panel and check 'Axes' to display the axis of each bone. Compare them to a good finger and if they're different you can change the roll angle for each bone individually by clicking the bone icon and altering the Roll setting to match a good finger.

Comment: ok so I  adjusted all the bones in edit mode so the z axis it pointing down but when i jump back into pose mode they reset the other way. ill keep this thread up but ill restart it from scratch

Comment: We'd need to see the blend file to investigate further. Upload it to [pasteall.org/blend](https://pasteall.org/blend/).

Comment: Just a thought: Do you have **any** keyframes set on your object yet? If so, the roll may be reverting to a 'rest' pose when you go into pose mode.